# Does anyone know if there is an IDE with explicit support for Ember.JS?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, ember.js, ide

Wanted to know if there is a good IDE with full support for Ember.JS not just basic JS. Or is there are any command line tooling or code generating tools like Grunt for Backbone.JS?

Answer (score 1):

I have nothing for IDE with intellisense for EmberJS, but [Sublime](http://www.sublimetext.com/2) is usually the go-to program of choice for development in Javascript. With a few packages and a jslinter you can get cracking straight away.

In the editor, there are things called 'snippets' that allow you to type a key combination, and a large portion of the code will be instantly filled out for you. For instance [this repo](https://github.com/arturgrigor/sublime-emberjs-snippets/tree/master/Handlebars) has a set that you can add to your Sublime application to help you get going. Apart from that, there's nothing really that can help you code faster and easier as having an automatic Jslinter (or jshinter depending on how much you hate Crockford) and a nice set of snippets.

Answer (score 1):

With [ember-rails](https://github.com/emberjs) you can generate an Ember.js app structure as well as controllers, models, etc. Find the generators [here](https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails/tree/master/lib/generators/ember).

There is also a ember.js package for [Bower](https://github.com/twitter/bower). Have a look at [Yeoman](http://yeoman.io/), which uses Bower for package management.